# WebClient.DownloadFile path problems

Tags: c#, .net

I am using WebClient.DownloadFile to download an image to a local repository as follows:

```
            WebClient myWC = new WebClient();
            myWC.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);
            string photoPath = @"\images\Employees\" + employee + ".jpg";
            myWC.DownloadFile(userResult[12].Values[0].Value.ToString(), photoPath);
```

My expected results were as follows: My web app is deployed here:

> C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebApp

I expected this to save the photo to

> C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebApp\images\Employees...

Instead, all my photos get saved here:

> C:\images\Employees

I guess I don't completely understand the `DownloadFile` method because I felt like the path should be relative to the directory the app is deployed in. How can I change the path so that it is relative to the directory of the app?

**Note:** I don't want to use a physical path because I have a Dev and QA site and I don't want the paths to break if things get moved around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In an ASP.NET application you could use the [`Server.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) method to map to a physical folder within your web site relative to the root of your site (which is represented by `~`):

```
string photoPath = Server.MapPath("~/images/Employees/" + employee + ".jpg");
```

Comment: U can user `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("")`

Answer (score 2):

The leading backslash in your `photoPath` makes the path an absolute path starting at the root directory (`C:\` in your example). Do make it a relative path just remove the leading backslash:

```
string photoPath = @"images\Employees\" + employee + ".jpg";
```

**Remark:** `DownloadFile(...)` will not create the directory for you. Make sure it's there:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("images\Employees");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string photoPath = @"images\Employees\" + employee + ".jpg";
```

doesn't work in powershell and gives the following error:

```
At line:1 char:22
+ string photoPath = @"images\Employees\" + employee + ".jpg";
+                      ~
No characters are allowed after a here-string header but before the end of the line.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedCharactersAfterHereStringHeader
```